# Lithium PHP Framework - posted data empty when receive PATCH requests ???

Tags: php, frameworks, request, patch, lithium

So, I'm sending `PATCH` requests to a server side, built with `Lithium PHP Framework`, and in side the controller actions I see that the `$request->data` is empty ... and I can't use the sent data.

What could be the problem? ...

(If I change the client side to send POST requests - then all is fine ... but the `Lithium PHP Framework` rely on the request type ... and so it breaks if the request type is `PATCH` ? ...)

Comment: Show us the code that is making the `PATCH` request.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Lithium is used? Lithium didn't support PATCH method until [this commit](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/commit/393714b60d199ca2cf96fe37ffbb6d8adc14923c). See how support for PATCH was added in that commit so it should populate $request->data now.

Try to update to the most recent version of Lithium or just apply that patch to check if it solves the problem.

Comment: It's strange, cause when I dump `$this->_methods` in the controller - the `PATCH` requests handling is described there. I'll check that commit though. (But for the moment I modified the client side to send POST requests, and it's fine.)

Comment: Yeah, that commit takes PATCH request data from `php://input` and puts it into `$request->data`. Prior to that commit patch method would still be routed but no data populated. Glad POST is working for you and it's sorted.

Answer (score 0):

What web server are you using ? I had the same problem with `li3_server` library (https://github.com/daschl/li3_server). I changed to `nginx` and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm using it locally, on Apache, on Kubuntu 12.04. The dev server we're using is with Ubuntu server, again with Apache.